# Androidアプリで、1つのアプリで、機能別の2つのアイコンを作成することは可能ですか？

Tags: android, android-studio

Androidアプリの作成についてですが、1つのアプリをインストールして、機能別の2つのアイコンを作成することは可能でしょうか？

そのようなアプリに遭遇したことがなくて、不可能なのかもと思って、困っています。

たとえば、アイコンAは「実行」、アイコンBは「設定」
といったように、機能別のアイコンを、Androidスマホ画面に出したいです。

Windowsのソフトでは、1つのソフトをインストールすると、関連するアイコンが複数作成されることは多いです。

Comment: とても古い11年前の記事ですがこんなのがあるようです。[複数の起動アイコンを登録する](https://monoist.itmedia.co.jp/mn/articles/1203/29/news001.html) 同じ名前のファイルは今でも使っているようなので出来るかもしれませんね。[アプリ マニフェストの概要](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=ja)

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます。
まさにこれです。

Answer (score 0):

できますよ？
たぶんですが…。
むかーしむかしやって見たような気がします。
ネットでやり方とか出てると思いますよ？
一応ですが、その部分の違う範囲にも言えるので知っておいた方が良いこととしてですが…。

一応Androidは画面側とJava側で分かれて作るようになっているように見えますが…。

実際のところは、むかしからずっと作ってる人だと痛いほど痛感していますが
昔はほぼJavaソースのみでほぼUIとかSwingみたいにして作る方法が主流でした。

言いたいのは何かというと、Java側でUIは操作が大抵そろっているっていうことです。
ですので、こういう答えをしました。

長くなりましたが、アイコンをオブジェクトにJava側のふるまいに伴って変えたりするのは
出来るようですよ。

```
//こういう感じでいけるかなと思います。
public void doChange(Button btn, String mess) {
  if(!mess.equals("")){
    btn.setText(mess);
  }
  btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.iconimage);
}
```